Are there any functions like SendMessage() or SendMessageTimeout() that goes through the message queue instead of calling the windows procedure?
Essentially, I'm looking for a function like PostMessage() that would be synchronous, so it doesn't return until the message has been processed. It doesn't necessarily have to be a function that does that (Because I don't think that there is any) but I'm looking for a way to track the amount of time it takes for a windows message to get processed starting from the time it enters the message queue. SendMessage() would've been very useful but it bypasses the message queue. It's also probably useful to mention that I'm sending the message to a completely different program so it's not on the same thread.
I've tried SendMessage(), but it's not what I'm looking for because I need something that goes through the message queue. PostMessage() isn't suitable either because it returns immediately so I can't track the message. I've looked into hooking to check all the messages getting processed by the other program but I'm trying to find something simpler.
Quick edit to give context: To the people asking why I'm trying this, I'm doing tests to automate the calculation of time for clients applications to recover after they all reconnect to a server at the same time. When they reconnect, they usually freeze and what I found is that the client windows stop processing messages, but if I use SendMessage(), then they still get processed. To the guy that said I need to do automation properly: I'm not sure if this is what you meant but I can't modify the source code of the software that I'm trying to measure so that is not an option, I have to do it from an external software.

"a function that goes through the message queue" doesn't really mean anything and  there are lots misunderstanding in your question like "PostMessage is synchronous" or "SendMessage bypasses the message queue". Also you can't spy a message queue you don't own using public APIs (but you can hack your machine if you have sufficient rights of course). You should clarify what you really mean.

Using SendMessage...() to a different thread may not put the message itself in the target thread's queue, but it is still dependent on the target thread processing its queue before the message is dispatched. In any case, if you really want to test the timing of the target thread's message queue, you might try having the sender log the current time, and then hook the target window and post a message to its queue, and have the hook log the current time again. Or, maybe use CreateEvent() and have the hook signal the event, then have the poster time how long it takes the event to be signaled.

Why do you want to time this? Under normal circumstances, i.e. when the window thread isn't busy, the queue is largely empty.

but it bypasses the message queue - why you decide this? This of course is wrong. SendMessage for another thread always put message to it queue. So simply use SendMessage and all

You probably need to stop trying to fake input like this and do automation properly

@RbMm That's not correct. A cross-thread sent message is queued, but goes to a queue distinctly different from that for queued ("posted") messages. The specific difference is that cross-thread sent messages aren't surfaced by any of the message-retrieval functions.

@IInspectable you by self write "cross-thread sent message is queued". I also say this. I nothing say about different or same way queued compare to PostMessage. Really how is possible send/post message to another thread ? Only insert message in some DB ( queue) and notify target thread about this

There is nothing built in to do this. The receiving program can compare the current time to the GetMessageTime to determine how long the message waited in the queue. If you cannot change the receiving program, then you'll have to hook its GetMessage.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@RaymondChen Thank you very much, that's all I needed to know. I'll look into hooking.

Promote @RaymondChen 's comment to answer.

There is nothing built in to do this. The receiving program can
compare the current time to the GetMessageTime to determine how long
the message waited in the queue. If you cannot change the receiving
program, then you'll have to hook its GetMessage.

See WH_GETMESSAGE.
